# How to call a dataTables date range search in IE?

Tags: jquery, date, internet-explorer, datatables

I'm using the [datatables](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) search API to filter table results between two dates on a column containing unix dates. Testing this on Chrome the search works as expected.

But running the website on `IE 11` this search function doesn't filter the records on the datatable. I debugged by stepping into the console on IE doesn't show any error messages for the associated code.

This is the code that performs the filter based on a `startDate` and `endDate` passed in. It filters the `colValue` at index 10 using these two values.

**Format of date search variables:**

```
startDate = moment().subtract(1, 'week').day(1).format("MMM DD YYYY");
endDate = moment().day(1).format("MMM DD YYYY");
var colValue= moment.unix($(this).data('order')).format("DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm A");
```

**Inputs to date search:**

```
min is 1413195180000
max is 1413195180000
colValue is 1413195180000
```

**Filtering code:**

```
/* Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between          two values */
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            var min = startDate;
            var max = endDate;
            var colValue = Date.parse(data[10]); // use data for the Last_Updated column


            if ((isNaN(min) && isNaN(max)) ||
                 (isNaN(min) && colValue <= max) ||
                 (min <= colValue && isNaN(max)) ||
                 (min <= colValue && colValue <= max)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    );
```

**Question:**

How can you call dataTables date range search API in IE?

Comment: I don't see anything jumping out at me that would be a source of an error. Your search extension looks fine, moment has IE support, your logic looks right, and all of the functions you call are supported as far back as IE9. Could you try to create a demo that reproduces the error?

Comment: @mhodges I set up a gist of my setup here, testing in the jsbin it shows 0 results for a valid search range. Any ideas? https://jsbin.com/zulokupumi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I think I figured it out - take a look at my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several things going wrong, but I will try to address each of them so you can know how I arrived at my solution.

#### Best Practices / Conventions

- You had a document ready function nested inside of another document ready function -- `$(function () {...})` inside `$(document).ready(function () {...})`
- The DataTable search function extension should be outside your document ready function
- You had the wrong selector specified in `setDateRange` function. Also, should set `.val()` on input, rather than `.html()`
- You can reuse your `setDateRange` function by calling it from your `init` function

#### What Was Causing It To Break

- The line `var colValue = Date.parse(data[1]);` was returning `NaN` every time **because `Date.parse` only works on date objects, and data[1] is a string**. The correct way to do it would be `new Date(parseInt(data[1])).getTime()`
- I was also seeing really weird things happening with even just the most basic of library function calls. I figured it was library versioning mismatches, so I plugged in newer/updated versions of the libraries you were using and that helped tremendously

Here is a working demo of what you are trying to accomplish - please let me know if this works for you, or if you have any questions!

```js
//Date range vars
var startDate = new Date();
var endDate = new Date();
var laststartDate = new Date();
var lastendDate = new Date();
startDate = moment().subtract(1, 'week').day(1).format("MMM DD YYYY");
endDate = moment().day(1).format("MMM DD YYYY");

/* Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
    var min = new Date(startDate).getTime();
    var max = new Date(endDate).getTime();
    var colValue = new Date(parseInt(data[1])).getTime(); // use data for the Last_Updated column

    if (!isNaN(colValue) && ((isNaN(min) && isNaN(max)) ||
      (isNaN(min) && colValue <= max) ||
      (min <= colValue && isNaN(max)) ||
      (min <= colValue && colValue <= max))) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
);


//Once the Document DOM is ready..
$(function() {
  function setDateRange(start, end) {
      $('#dateRangeLbl .date-range-input').val(start.format('MMM DD, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMM DD, YYYY'));
      startDate = Date.parse(start);
      endDate = Date.parse(end);
      historyTable.draw();
    }
    //Init the escalation DataTable and
    //Set sorting desc by Updated time.
  var historyTable = $('#escalation').DataTable({
    "order": [
      [1, "desc"]
    ],
    colReorder: true,
    responsive: true,
    dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
  });


  //Input event listener for date range picker
  $('#dateRangeInput').daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
    }
  }, setDateRange);

  //init the default date range filter on refresh
  init();

  function init() {
    var d = new Date("October 13, 2014");
    startDate = Date.parse(d);
    endDate = Date.now();
    setDateRange(moment(startDate), moment(endDate));
  }
}); //end $(document).ready
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />

  <!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="tableViewContainer" style="padding-left:0px;">


    <div class="table-responsive">
      <div class="table-responsive max-width-table" id="datatable-wrapper">

        <div class="form-group form-inline pull-right" id="tblDateRange">
          <label id="dateRangeLbl" class="date-range-label">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> 
            <input class="input-sm top-buffer pull-right date-range-input" id="dateRangeInput" type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2016 - 12/25/2016" />

          </label>
        </div>

        <table id="escalation" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0">


          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Last Updated</th>
              <th>Formated Date</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1413195180000</td>
              <td>10/13/2014</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>1713195110000</td>
              <td>04/15/2024</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>1943195110000</td>
              <td>07/30/2031</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>3043195110000</td>
              <td>06/07/2066</td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```